# Query to fetch latest record from different select query and then do union all

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to write query like below:

```
select top 1 * from table_A 
Join table B ---some more table is possible
where conditon_1
order by create_date
union all
select top 1 * from table B 
---some more table is possible
where conditon_2
order by create_date
```

So I need to get the latest record from two select queries based on different condition and then do union all.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected results (in formatted text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can re-write query as given below

```sql
SELECT * FROM
(select top 1 * from table_A 
Join table B ---some more table is possible
where conditon_1
order by create_date) as t1

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM 
(select top 1 * from table B 
---some more table is possible
where conditon_2
order by create_date) as t2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that directly. Use `CTE` for the 2 query

```
with
cte1 as
(
    select top 1 * from table_A 
    Join table B ---some more table is possible
    where conditon_1
    order by create_date
),
cte2 as
(
    select top 1 * from table B 
    ---some more table is possible
    where conditon_2
    order by create_date
)
select * from cte1
union all
select * from cte2
```